# Position text right next to logo png image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to place my "text" right next to the logo using css, please see screenshot below. How do I position the text "John Doe, DDS" right next to the logo? Please help, I'm a newbie in CSS.Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This can be done in a number of ways, I would suggest looking into [css floats](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). The idea would be that the logo was floated left, allowing the text to move up beside it (assuming it was the next DOM element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very complicated. You can use `float: left;` on both your logo and text. It works best to make a `div` around them, so you get something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='logo>
    <img src='logo.png' />
</div>
<div class='text'>
    <h1>JOHN DOE, DDS</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo{
    height: auto;
    width: auto; /* makes the div same size as content */
    float: left;
}
.text{
    height: auto;
    width: auto; /* makes the div same size as content */
    float: left; 
}
```

Now you can also add a `top: something` to the `.text` if you want your text to be in the position it is in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation, you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You could float both elements next to each other or display them as inline blocks. Since inline blocks are inline elements, they will be positioned next to each other. Check out the following example:

```css
.logo,.heading
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.logo
{
  font-size: 35px;
  color: red;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" width="50" alt="John Doe">
</div>
<div class="heading">
  <h1>
    John Doe
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, your solution works perfectly!